# Error : List object is not callable

Tags: python, enthought

This is the code that I have written in Enthought Canopy to adjust the axes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

x = np.arange(-3,3,0.001)
axe = plt.axes()
axe.set_xlim([-5, 5])
axe.set_ylim([0, 1.0])
axe.set_xticks([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
axe.set_yticks([0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0])
plt.plot(x, norm.pdf(x))
plt.plot(x, norm.pdf(x, 1.0, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

and I am getting the following error :

```
 %run "c:\users\tejpal\appdata\local\temp\tmppdy2am.py"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\tejpal\appdata\local\temp\tmppdy2am.py in <module>()
      5 x = np.arange(-3,3,0.001)
      6 axe = plt.axes()
----> 7 axe.set_xlim([-5, 5])
      8 axe.set_ylim([0, 1.0])
      9 axe.set_xticks([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Please help me with this!

Comment: Your program works well for me when I run it in regular Python 2.7. Did you try to execute it with the commandline `python tmppdy2am.py`?

Comment: Code is working for me. Graph is generating.

Comment: Your code works well for me. Show the output of `import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)`

Comment: Okay so I run the program in the Canopy Command Prompt and its working.But in the Editor its still showing the Error.

Comment: the output of : import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__) came out to be 1.5.1

Comment: Also works fine for me when run from the Canopy editor, or directly in the Canopy Python panel. Please insert `print axe; print axe.set_xlim` after line 6. What is the output?

Comment: add the line: `print type(axe.setlim)` just before the error line to make sure it is executable.

Answer (score -1):

You might do it before you do the assignment，example:
`plt.xticks = []`,
then you `plt.xticks()` again,
warning "'list' object is not callable".
restart~~

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.